# DRF как передавать данные массивом?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Есть у меня модель **Profile**, а также модель **Rating**:

```py
class Profile(models.Model):
    ....

class Rating(models.Model):
    profile = models.ForeignKey(
        Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="rating", 
        verbose_name="Рейтинг", blank=True, null=True
    )
    rating = models.IntegerField("Оценка")
```

Я передаю данные о рейтинге через такой **сериализатор**:

```py
class RatingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # Рейтинг специалистов

    class Meta:
        model = Rating
        fields = ['rating']


class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # Профиль юзера

    rating = RatingSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = [
            ...
            'rating'
        ]
```

Проблема в том, что данные возвращаются мне как массив обьектов, однако мне нужно, чтобы это был массив со значениями из полей rating, то есть:
[5, 3, 4, 4, 5]
Вопрос, как это сделать?

Пока что выдает таким образом:

```
"rating": [  
        {  
            "rating": 5  
        },  
        {  
            "rating": 4  
        },  
        {  
            "rating": 5  
        }  
 ],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class RatingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # Рейтинг специалистов

    class Meta:
        model = Rating
        fields = ['rating']

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        ret = super().to_representation(instance)
        return ret['rating']
```